# Is there any possibility of creating view or table based on the output of a dynamically opened ref cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have learnt how to return a dynamically opened ref cursor. Now based on the output, I want to create a table or a view.

Input table:

```
   create table sales
    (s_sale_name varchar2(20),
    s_date_sal date,
    s_qty number(10)
    );
```

Records

```
insert into sales values ('Norb','10-MAR-2019',10000);
insert into sales values ('Bert','10-MAR-2019',5000);
insert into sales values ('Alba','10-MAR-2019',4000);
insert into sales values ('Rob','10-MAR-2019',200000);
insert into sales values ('Norb','11-MAR-2019',5000);
insert into sales values ('Bert','11-MAR-2019',13000);
insert into sales values ('Rob','11-MAR-2019',80000);
insert into sales values ('Norb','12-MAR-2019',1000);
insert into sales values ('Bert','12-MAR-2019',4000);
insert into sales values ('Rob','12-MAR-2019',40000);
insert into sales values ('Alba','12-MAR-2019',2000);
```

Query output

```
sales_name 10-MAR-2019 11-MAR-2019 12-MAR-2019 
Norb             10000        5000        1000
Bert              5000       13000        4000 
Alba              4000           0        2000 
Rob             200000       80000       40000
```

Now the result should be saved in a table or a view. I have learnt how to return a dynamically opened ref cursor so far.

------Here is the procedure I used -----------

```
create or replace package p_sales_pkg 
as 
type rc is ref cursor;
procedure get_query( p_cursor in out rc, p_start date, p_end date );
end;
/

create or replace package body p_sales_pkg
as
 procedure get_query( p_cursor in out rc, p_start date, p_end date )
 is
 l_query long := 'select s_name ';
 begin
  for i in 1 .. trunc(p_end)-trunc(p_start)+1
 loop
 l_query := l_query || ', sum( decode( trunc(s_date), ' ||
 'to_date( ''' || to_char(p_start+i-1,'yyyymmdd') ||
 ''', ''yyyymmdd'' ), s_qty, 0 )) "' ||
 to_char(p_start+i-1) || '"';
 end loop;
l_query := l_query || ' from sales group by s_name';
 open p_cursor for l_query;
 end;
 end;
 /

set autoprint on



var x refcursor

exec nw_demo_pkg.get_query( :x, '10-MAR-19', '13-MAR-19' );
```

Comment: Can you post the query which resulted to this output ? I don't see any symmetry in the result. The dynamic sql to create view or  table depends on the columns of the query.

Comment: Ref Cursors are a PL/SQL construct, we can't use them in regular SQL. So you have a choice. If you have a static result set structure and you always want to populate the same table, use PL/SQL collections to drive a FORALL insert. But if you want to have a variable ref cursor structure (different columns every time) and so different target tables then you need Method 4 dynamic SQL, which is highly advanced and rather complicated. [Find out more](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422)

Comment: Rereading your question - it is rather unclear - but it seems like you may want to use a Ref Cursor to drive the SELECT part of a CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT statement. Well we definitely can't do that. Nor build a view with a ref cursor. You'd have to use dynamic SQL to do that.

Comment: @XIN, Thanks for your solution. I have updated accordingly. Please have a look because the solution you provide should give the expected output.

Comment: @NorbertWupona . Unfortunately, you cannot have `execute immediate` twice as its the case in your statement. Somehow you can only use the `Query` in the method shown below;

Answer (score 1):

This is really a very nice and challenging question. I disagree on the @APC point on `SELECT part of a CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT statement. Well we definitely can't do that`. What i believe is to every problem in Oracle, there exists a solution.

You requirement can be achieved using a `NESTED TABLE`. See below:

Set Up:

```
create  table sales
    (s_sale_name varchar2(20),
    s_date_sal date,
    s_qty number(10)
    );

 /     
insert into sales values ('Norb','10-MAR-2019',10000);
insert into sales values ('Bert','10-MAR-2019',5000);
insert into sales values ('Alba','10-MAR-2019',4000);
insert into sales values ('Rob','10-MAR-2019',200000);
insert into sales values ('Norb','11-MAR-2019',5000);
insert into sales values ('Bert','11-MAR-2019',13000);
insert into sales values ('Rob','11-MAR-2019',80000);
insert into sales values ('Norb','12-MAR-2019',1000);
insert into sales values ('Bert','12-MAR-2019',4000);
insert into sales values ('Rob','12-MAR-2019',40000);
insert into sales values ('Alba','12-MAR-2019',2000);

---Created an Object of Sales table to hold intermediate result
create or replace  type  sales_obj is OBJECT
    (obj_sale_name varchar2(20),
     obj_date_sal date,
     obj_qty number(10)
    );
/
-- Table of Sales Object.
create or replace type vtest1Tab is table of sales_obj;
/
```

Anonymous Block to Create table `ccc`:

```
DECLARE 
 VAR VTEST1TAB ; 
 vsql varchar2(500);

BEGIN 

  vsql := 'create table ccc(col1) NESTED TABLE COL1 STORE AS TAB1 
           as 
           Select cast(multiset(Select * from SALES) as VTEST1TAB )
           from dual           
          ';    

  Execute immediate vsql ; 

END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> Select p.* 
     from ccc c, 
     table(c.COL1) p ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3576753) , The reply by "Zlatko Sirotic" covers exactly how to identify columns of the cursor and print them.

Look for "dyn_fetch", as the package is generic enough, it can work with any query for printing data. You can use the same approach to insert the data into a table that is created dynamically.

Comment: I will check it and revert to you. Thanks